# Run an NUnit 3.5 smoke test from Octopus Deploy

Tags: octopus-deploy

I have an Octopus project which deploys 2 websites and a web API.  I have written an NUnit 3.5 test which runs a basic Selenium test to make sure all the components are up and running.  The NUnit Selenium test is built in the my build server (TFS 2015) as is the other code.  It would be nice if Octopus could get the latest version of my test and run it against the deployed environment.

The build could deploy the test to a file share or to the Octopus nuget feed however the nuget feed would be better because it's versioned.  I don't know how to get the test from the feed and execute it.  Also there is a step definition for NUnit2 but not NUnit3.  There must be a recommended way to deal with this scenario!

Would it be a good idea to set-up a Jenkins server to handle all the tests for Octopus?

Answer (score 2):

NUnit 3.5 takes a different approach from NUnit 2.  Unit tests can be 'self-hosted' in their own .exe file instead of running them via the nunit runner.

Convert your NUnit project into a console app and add NUnitLite nuget package to the project.  This will add a new Program.cs file which allows you to run the test simply but calling the outputted EXE file.  There are some additional details [in the NUnit docs](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/NUnitLite-Runner).

The script file should be run from a package so that Octopus can load the nuget package.